# in css transition how to fade just one image and not the entire container?

Tags: css, web, transition

I'm a css newbie. How to flip an image linked to url on a html page (not background image) to show some text? 
Alternatively for fade out,how to fade an image on hover? this is the code I tried, it doesn't work properly. It's fading the entire container with all the images instead of just 1 image at a time.

```
.withfadeout {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-opacity: 0.2;
}
.withfadeout:hover {
opacity: 0.25;
```

}

I removed the fadeout class but the site is still fading out everything.
Many thanks.

Comment: can you show what have you tried so far? please post your code and whatever you've researched

Comment: Do you want to implement [this](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/jquery-flip/) ?

Comment: thank you @Nimish Think jquery is a bit forward for me, currently trying to get css fade work

Answer (score 0):

without jQuery. I think you should give an id to each image
jQuery make that easier.